# $\infty! = \sqrt{2\pi}$?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, factorial, infinity, infinite-product

The YouTube video ["Infinity Factorial"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFVUJEMjD2A&ab_channel=BiBenBap) by BiBenBap says that $\infty! = \sqrt{2\pi}$.

First of all, isn't the factorial operator an arithmetic operator? It is just multiplication following more specific rules. So, if the factorial operator is an arithmetic operator, then $\infty! =$ undefined, since arithmetic on infinity isn't allowed.

Past that, if we write out the factorial, then the answer is still undefined:

$$\infty \times (\infty -1) \cdots (\infty - (\infty -2)) \times (\infty - (\infty-1))$$

Given that any number substracted/added to infinity is infinity, then the last factors of the factorial are zero. $\infty \times 0 = $ undefined. If we move the parantheses however, those subtractions become additions, meaning we've got $0$, plus some number. Well, if that's allowed (which it isn't, since arithmetic isn't allowed on infinity), then we just get infinity times and infinite number of infinities, times an infinite number of finite numbers. That would obviously be infinity.

The math used in the linked video is far beyond me. Could someone explain how that video is wrong/right and how I am wrong/right?

Comment: smells like a faux-notation trick akin to [the diverging infinite sum "equal"ing -1/12](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/does-123-really-equal-112/) via Riemann-zeta assignation.  am curious to learn about this. notice that comments are disabled on the Yt video in question.

Comment: The following fact is an example of Ramanujan summation, which is a way of assigning Convergent values to divergent series.

Comment: *"First of all, isn't the factorial operator an arithmetic operator?"* The factorial is introduced that way, but the function can be extended to real numbers by way of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). It's not-uncommon to use continue using factorial notation, though, so that we can write stuff like "$(-1/2)!=\sqrt{\pi}$". ... Making sense of $\infty!$ is another matter, however.

Comment: It worths mentioning the fact that, Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^{s}}$ converges only for $\Re(s)>1$, and so do it's derivative. And since he considered $s=0$, it's obvious that it diverges. But he calculated the $\zeta'(0)$ which is $\frac{\ln 2\pi}{2}$, and it's not the same thing as infinite product of factorials due to reason mentioned.

Comment: Be very cautious when you see videos or whatever playing a bit too much with $0$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The final result in the video is not wrong. But what much of the video says/does is wrong. $\infty !$ is a nonsensical symbol. Think of this as any other advertisement you see on TV: it may have some real things, but a lot of it is phrased misleadingly/deceptively to get people to click/view it.

The factorial is an arithmetic operation defined only on non-negative integers (as you have noted in your second sentence), and this definition is done recursively, i.e we define

> - $0!= 1$ by definition
> - For any $n\geq 0$, we define $(n+1)!= (n+1)\cdot n!$

So, we can only take factorials of non-negative integers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$

Trying to somehow claim that $\infty !=\sqrt{2\pi}$ is then a nonsensical assertion based on the above definition (because $\infty !$ is not even defined based on our above definition).

---

**The correct statement.**

The correct statement (i.e no wishy-washy handwaving nonsense) is that Riemann's zeta function is such that $\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$. What does this mean? You say that the math used in the video is far beyond you, so fine, let me just tell you parts of "what" is being said.

Riemann was a famous mathematician, and one of his works was about a certain function. This function has the symbol $\zeta: \Bbb{C}\setminus \{1\}\to\Bbb{C}$, and it is what we now call "Riemann's Zeta function". What does this function do? Well, it takes a complex number $s\neq 1$ as an input, and it outputs a certain complex number $\zeta(s)$. The exact definition of $\zeta$ is not really important to us right now (and indeed giving a correct definition for this is something one can only do after a half-semester course in complex analysis). All you need to know is that one can prove that the function $\zeta$ is differentiable at $s=0$, and that
\begin{align}
\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi) \tag{$*$}.
\end{align}

So, the correct statement is $(*)$. This is 100% correct mathematics (I didn't fully watch the video, so I won't comment on whether the Youtuber's explanation of this result is correct). But, rest assured that $(*)$ can be given a completely airtight proof. HOWEVER, what is utterly nonsense is going from $(*)$ to the statement that $\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$. This is what I was talking about in my first paragraph: there is some real mathematical content in this video (i.e the definition of $\zeta$ and the calculation of its derivative at $s=0$). However, the video is also full of "false advertisements" in that it makes absurd claims like $\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$.

One has to really turn a blind eye to several mathematically incorrect steps (such as calling $P=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots$, which is really just $\infty$, and doing arithmetic with that), and then hand wave alot of details to even heuristically try to justify the relationship between the correct equation $(*)$ and the nonsensical $\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$.

---

**Final Remarks.**

The zeta function is also notorious in "everyday math" claims, because of the somewhat (in)famous $1+2+3+4+\cdots =-\frac{1}{12}$ nonsense. Anyway, to finish off, the statement that $\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$ makes as much sense as saying "the earth and moon are both round, therefore, the earth and moon are the same thing".

Comment: by the way, you might be interested to watch Mathologer's video [Numberphile v. Math: the truth about $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$](https://youtu.be/YuIIjLr6vUA). I think this is a very instructive video which sets straight many of the basic issues (I know it's not exactly the same question as you're asking, but it's very related to the other common question regarding $\zeta$).

Comment: $\infty!$ very much makes sense in the sense of a limit (which would be $\infty$). He’s just applying theorems without checking the premises.

Comment: @Lazy I certainly agree $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n!=\infty$, but I was being super picky here with my phrasing because this question is really about getting definitions straight. I said (correctly) that the symbol $\infty!$ makes no sense according to the recursive definition of the factorial; see my paranthetical remark in the first part of my answer.

Comment: In my answer I am not talking about "what possible meaning can we assign to the a-priori undefined symbol blablabla". My purpose with this answer is to make a clear distinction between what the actual mathematically correct statement is vs what a nonsensical "advertisement-like" statement is.

Comment: But that is not related to the question. It is clear from the video that $\infty!$ is seen as limit. This is a bit like saying: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k$ makes no sense, as sums can only be finite.

Comment: @Lazy you and I both know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n!\neq \sqrt{2\pi}$, and in my answer I have already made it very clear that the youtuber is being sloppy with titles and symbols. $\infty!$ in the youtuber's video does not stand for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n!$, rather it should be interpreted as $e^{-\zeta'(0)}$ (along with a completely erroneous use of the definition of $\zeta$ as a series). So, I'm not really sure why you say my answer isn't related to the question.

Comment: Yes, in the YouTuber’s video it *does* stand for the limit of $n!$. There problem starts because he assumes these two things to be equal, which is not true. Your answer surely is valuable, but I just want to point out you’re shifting blame to the wrong spots.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the video is irrelevant, as it’s only about calculating the value of $\zeta'(0)$. The shady part is actually happening in 4:33, as he is ignoring the rules when differentiation may be pulled into a series. As $\lim\log(n)=\infty$ it is impossible for that series *not* to be $\infty$.

Basically we have a sequence of functions $f_k$ and take the series $\sum_k f_k$. Supposing that this converges we then want to take the derivative $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\sum_k f_k(k)$. What this guy then is doing is to say
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\sum_k f_k(x) = \sum_k \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}f_k(x) $$

Indeed we have a Theorem that states that this is true for all points in an interval $[a,b]$ under the conditions that the series of the derivatives converges uniformly.

But this is not true for the functions he is using!

So this is a case of: If we implicitly assume that the surprising property $P$ is true we can suddenly prove that the slightly weaker property $Q$ is true.

Comment: What rules are being ignored, exactly?

Comment: @William $\sum_k \log(k)k^{-s}$ does not converge uniformly on an interval around $0$, it does not even converge pointwise.

Answer (score 1):

No. The video is wrong. The regularized value of this infinite product is different. See the details [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426129/whats-the-true-regularized-value-of-product-of-all-natural-numbers).